# Transformar variable tipo nulo a entero

Tags: php, php5

Básicamente lo que tengo en mente es esto:

```
<?php
$u = isset($_POST['usuarioingresado']);
$v1 = is_null($u);
if($v1==null){$v1==0; echo $v1;}
```

Comment: Lo que quieres es que si `$_POST['usuarioingresado']` no está definida (que se convierte implícitamente a `null`) el contenido de `$v1` sea 0, ¿estoy en lo cierto? Fíjate que estás haciendo una comparación y no una asignación en `$v1==0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu código no funciona como esperas por varios motivos. Dividiré mi respuesta en tres apartados para ayudarte a entender y corregir los errores que has cometido.

### Comprobación de definición y no contenido

En la siguiente línea:

```
$u = isset($_POST['usuarioingresado']);
```

Estás asignando a `$u` un valor booleano que valdrá `true` o `false`, nunca valdrá `null`, por lo que `is_null($u)` SIEMPRE dará `false` y la comprobación `$v1==null` SIEMPRE será cierta.

### Comparación en vez de asignación

En la siguiente línea:

```
if($v1==null){$v1==0; echo $v1;}
```

En `$v1==0;` estás haciendo una comparación `==` (y no una asignación `=`) de una variable, como hemos visto en el punto anterior, que siempre vale `false` con el número `0`.

El resultado de dicha comparación, por no ser estricta (`===`), sería `true`. Pero ese resultado no se guarda en ningún sitio porque no hay ninguna asignación que lo haga (`=`).

Así que el `echo $v1;` intentará mostrar el contenido de una variable que sigue valiendo `false` (recordemos que en ningún momento se hizo una asignación `=`, sólo una comparación `==`, por lo que su contenido sigue inalterado).

### Cómo hacer correctamente el trabajo

Tengamos en cuenta lo siguiente:

- El contenido de los datos almacenados en cada uno de los índices de `$_POST` son de tipo cadena de caracteres (string).
- Sólo obtendrás `null` en `$u` si el índice `usuarioingresado` de `$_POST` no está definido.

Así que el `isset()` debería hacer todo el trabajo y no deberías necesitar en ningún momento ese segundo `is_null()` para comprobar un fallo accediendo a dicho índice (que, por cierto, te provocaría un `NOTICE`).

Una forma de hacerlo en una única línea sería:

```
<?php
$u = isset($_POST['usuarioingresado']) ? $_POST['usuarioingresado'] : 0;
echo $u;
```

O bien, usando bloques condicionales:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['usuarioingresado'])) {
  $u = $_POST['usuarioingresado'];
} else {
  $u = 0;
}
echo $u;
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero yo prefiero `empty` a `isset` [por los motivos aquí expuestos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7191642/5587982). Sería tu mismo planteamiento, pero con `empty`, del siguiente modo: `$u = ( !empty($_POST['usuarioingresado']) ) ? $_POST['usuarioingresado'] : 0;` **Nótese** que `empty` va precedido con el signo `!`

Comment: Estoy contigo, pero depende del caso. Habrá ocasiones en el que una cadena de texto vacío sea un valor válido (por poner un ejemplo). Mientras no se aclare el uso exacto de este código no podremos elucubrar mucho más.

Comment: Correcto. El problema filosófico de lo nulo, lo vacío, la nada... no es de fácil resolución si no se tiene definido el concepto en el contexto de la aplicación.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que tener claros los conceptos de `isset()` y `is_null()`

- **is_null()**

  Comprueba si una variable es NULL. Si es null devuelve true.

  http://php.net/manual/es/function.is-null.php

---

- **isset()**

  Comprueba si la variable existe y es distinta de NULL.

  http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php

Aqui te dejo un enlace donde explica en profundidad las diferencias.
https://cybmeta.com/isset-is_null-y-empty-diferencias-y-ejemplos-de-uso

Por lo que tu código sería redundante. Estas comprobando por Tres veces si la variable es null. En el isset del post, en el is_null y cuando la igualas a NULL.

```
//Igualamos el post a una variable
//Si la variable no existe o es null entra en el if y se convierte en null
$u = (isset($_POST['usuarioingresado']) ? $_POST['usuarioingresado'] : null);

//Si es null lo ponemos a 0
if(is_null($u)){
   $u = 0;
}
//Pintamos la variable
echo $u;
```

Un saludo.